# Troubles in MPI : Use mpi to rewrite the program as a parallel program

Tags: c, mpi

Request:each process needs to calculate the distance between its own group and all points.
My code is as follows：

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include math.h
#include string.h
#include "mpi.h"

double **malloc_Array2D(int row, int col)
{

    int size = sizeof(double);
    int point_size = sizeof(double*);
    double **arr = (double **) malloc(point_size * row + size * row * col);
    if (arr != NULL)
    {
        memset(arr, 0, point_size * row + size * row * col);
        double *head = (double*)(arr + row);
        while (row--)
            arr[row] = head + row * col;
    }
    return (double**)arr;
}

void free_Aarray2D(void **arr)
{

    if (arr != NULL)
        free(arr);
}

double distance(double *pos1, double *pos2, int dim)
{

    int i;
    double dist = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
        dist += pow((pos2[i]-pos1[i]), 2.0);

    return sqrt(dist);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int np, myid;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    //open file
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("points.dat","r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("open file failure! exit!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //read the number of points
    int npoints;
    fscanf(fp, "There are %d points\n", &npoints);
    if(0==myid)
        printf("There are %d points\n", npoints);
    int nptsl_max = npoints/np; 
    if((npoints%np)!=0)
        nptsl_max++;

    double (*xi)[3];
    double **dist;
    int *ind = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*nptsl_max);
    xi  = (double (*)[3])malloc(sizeof(double)*nptsl_max*3);
    dist= malloc_Array2D(nptsl_max, npoints);

    int nptsl = 0; //local number of points
    char str[200];
    for(int i=0; i<npoints; i++)
    {
        if(myid == (i%np))
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %lf %lf", ind+nptsl, &xi[nptsl][0], &xi[nptsl][1], &xi[nptsl][2]);
            nptsl++;
        }
        else
            fgets(str, 200, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(int i=0; i<nptsl; i++)
        printf("point %4d on process %d\n", *(ind+i), myid);

    dist   = (myid == (np-1))?0     :(myid+1);
    source = (myid == 0)     ?(np-1):(myid-1);

    double (*yi)[3];
    yi  = (double (*)[3])malloc(sizeof(double)*nptsl_max*3);
    for(int i=0; i<nptsl; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            yi[i][j] = xi[i][j];

    for(int loop=0; loop < np)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<nptsl; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<npoints; j++)
            {
                dist[i][j] = distance(xi[i], xi[j], 3);
            }
        }
    }


    sprintf(filename, "dist_%d.dat",myid);
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    for(i=0; i<npoints; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%4d", ind[i]);
        for(j=0; j<npoints; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "  %f", dist[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);

    free(ind);
    free(xi);
    free_Aarray2D((void **)dist);

}
```

I don't know how to communicate messages.
I think it should be used **MPI_Bcas**t or **MPI_Gather** for communication.
But I can't solve this problem all the time.Can anyone help me?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So each process is reading a subset from a file, and you want to calculate the distance from each point in the sub-set to ALL the points?

Why is there a loop with a "loop" variable?

If you need to do one iteration for calculating the distances, it would probably be faster to have each process read the whole file entirely, calculate the distances for a subset and the use MPI_Gather to send all the distances to the root node that will write the result.

If you plan on doing several iterations, where in each iteration you also update the location of the points, then you need to also use MPI_Allgather to send/recv the points from the other processes.